# What about the structure theory in Baer *-rings?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, baer-rings

In the literature, Baer *-rings are called as the algebraic analogue of von Neumann alegars.

It is well-known that

**Theorem**. Every von-Neumann algebra is decomposed into a direct sum of the algebras of type $I$, type $II_1$ , type $II_{\infty}$ and type $III$.

What is last version of the above theorem that has been accomplished  in Baer *-rings?

Comment: Have you checked the book "Baer *-rings" by Berberian?